# Facebook FQL Searching Pages Using Partial String

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm trying to search for a company's different branches using a partial string. Here's the query I'm using:

> SELECT name, location, fan_count, talking_about_count, were_here_count
>   FROM page WHERE strpos(name, "Applebee's") >= 0 OR (name < 0)

I get the error:

> Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an
>   indexable column.

Name is listed as indexable, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function `CONTAINS()`:

```
SELECT name, location, fan_count, talking_about_count, were_here_count FROM page WHERE CONTAINS("Applebee's") and strpos(name, "Applebee's") >=0
```

This query will output all results which will contain Applebee's in name.

Comment: I have an additional question. Do you know how to have the company in the CONTAINS function only be the beginning of the partial string? For example, if I'm searching for branches of Hilton Hotel I would use CONTAINS("Hilton"). However, one of my first return results is "Paris Hilton" the person. The CONTAINS() doesn't recognize the usual wildcard characters such as *, %.

Comment: @Momo If Hilton should be the first word, then additional filter should be set to `strpos(name, "Hilton") = 0` (so we'll take only those names that start from Hilton)